# Specifying MSTest Host culture

Tags: c#, visual-studio, integration-testing, mstest, vsx

I'm trying to fix our project's integration tests suite, which is based on MSTest and tests an extension for Visual Studio. These MSTest tests run from within a new Visual Studio instance (which configured as the Test Host). During testing on different computers we found that, since different computers have slightly different regional settings (default Culture), the strings returned from Visual studio are also somewhat different in their formatting.

My question is whether there's any way, using MSTest with "VS IDE" as host, to set the default CultureInfo, so that we can get consistent results across our different test machines?

Comment: You can assign CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture and Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture in your [TestInitialize] method.

Comment: @HansPassant The thing is, we believe the culture-specific logic we are testing is done on the UI thread. By the time we reach our [TestInitialize] method, Visual Studio's UI thread has already been created, and so changing DefaultThreadCurrentCulture after the fact won't matter.

Comment: A church is a good place for beliefs.  Post repro code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Which platform are you running the tests on? Windows 8/Windows Server 2012, or Win 7/Svr 2008?

Comment: From my limited testing, setting `CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` will also update `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`, but only if it has not already been manually set.  As soon as you overwrite that value (which MSTest may be doing), it no longer "inherits" from the DefaultThreadCurrentCulture.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to solve the same problem, and finally came across the [AssemblyInitializeAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assemblyinitializeattribute.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).  You can use this to set `DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture` and `DefaultThreadCurrentCulture` before any of your tests run.

One important thing to keep in mind when using this attribute:

> Only one method in an assembly may be decorated with this attribute.

*Credit for the solution goes to [Bart Wullems](http://bartwullems.blogspot.com/2017/05/mstestsetting-culture-of-your-tests.html).*